# How do I tell how much weight I'm carrying?

Tags: killing-floor-2

In KF1 there was a weight indicator on the bottom left that would tell you your carrying capacity and what your current capacity was at.

Now I don't see it anywhere on the HUD, and nowhere on the Trader screen.

How do I tell how much weight I'm carrying?

Comment: In KF1, I only remember the weight indicator being on the Trader screen.  Then again, that's probably because it only really matters when you're getting new weapons.

Comment: @Powerlord It definitely was at the bottom as well, though like you say, it was of limited usefulness except to plan ahead or if you found a weapon drop. Tripwire seems to agree since it's not there anymore.

Comment: Do you need any more help with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an indicator in KF2 that tells you in the Trader how much weight you're carrying.  It's in the top-middle of the screen.  In the example shown here, taken from my own version as it is, I have a weight of 4 out of a total of 15.

[image: Killing Floor 2 Weight Indicator]

There are currently no indicators when actually outside of the Trader other than being unable to pick up weapons.

Comment: The carry weight is now shown in the HUD.